# Кодировка UTF-8

Tags: кодировка, utf-8, mysql

Как сделать, чтобы записи (данные) из Базы mysql отображались в кодировке utf-8 внутри компонента dbGrid. А также при insert и Update операциях отправлялись в необходимой utf-8 кодировке. Пробовал менять кодировку среды Embarcadero в настройках и пробовал менять в properties компонента dbGrid fonts-> charset на russian charset. Среди выпадающих кодировок ничего похожего на UTF-8 не нашлось. ПОМОГИТЕ!

Comment: CP65001 присутствует в списке?

Comment: Сама БД позволяет выставить кодировку таблиц? Везде советую использовать кодировку, в том числе и русского текста, кодировку utf8general-ci